# Create folder on /mnt/externel1

Tags: android

I want to create folder on `/mnt/externel1` (which is my external micro-sd card path) but when I create folder problematically  [  `file.mkdirs()`  ] it is returning `false`.

And when I am trying to download a file on that path by creating an outputStream it throwing an exception "Permission denied"

Note: android application not allowing to write on external micro-sd card.

your advise will helpful for me.

Answer (score 5):

Please add below permission in manifest file.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

you have to mentioned permission in manifest file when you want to write into sdcard.

Comment: I have already added this code in my manifest. I think that the this is problem of android api , i read somewhere that the android api version lower than 3.2 not support write on external microsd card (which path is /mnt/external1/)  plz reply.

Comment: Permission denied - error occured due to sdcard permission is not declared in manifest file.

Comment: i am declaring the path progmatically.

Comment: plz help. http://markmail.org/message/7hdcbi6o5kx3ybrq  and http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.android.devel/172094 showing that lower version not support the write.

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting Honeycomb, you can't write to the external SD card.

**Edit**

Just noticed the permission stuff - you should make sure that you've got the appropriate permissions. See Chirag Raval's answer.

Comment: yes i am using honeycomb (motorola xoom) 3.1 , so there is no way to perform this task? and what about the froyo and gingerbread? ...........any idea?    Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: There's no way to write to the external SD card in Honeycomb. It's not a problem in previous versions of Android.